# React Native Linear Gradient: Colors washed out

Tags: react-native, color-space

I'm using the [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) package to form a linear gradient. I've picked the exact same colors with color picker in XD design to form the same gradient in my app. Here is my code:

`<LinearGradient start={{x:0,y:0}} end={{x:1,y:1}} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} colors={['#D300B5', '#FF5400']} >...`

These hex values are the same values with the design, yet, here is the result compared with the design:

[image]

The colors are significantly washed out. I've checked the opacities to make sure everything is at 100%, there aren't anything over the gradient, the gradient view isn't extending beyond the screen, both XD, my Mac, and the iPhone X use the Display P3 color space.

Why are the colors washed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: This solution is iOS-only and applies to all colors used in app.*

After a long time of not being able to find out anything, I've created a patch of React Native itself, as the problem originates from how React Native creates colors itself in native code in `RCTConvert.m`:

`return [UIColor colorWithRed:... green:... blue:...]`

Switching both occurances (there are two as of writing) of `colorWithRed` to `colorWithDisplayP3Red` and rebuilding (don't forget as we're changing native code, hot reloading won't work) the app worked: Colors are now rendered in P3 color space. Please note that this approach changes *all* colors that you create/use in app, so every color will basically look more crisp.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thank you. This is the only solution that I could find for this answer.
Also, do you mind sharing the file that you have updated?

Comment: @AkashKaushik sure. I actually created a gist 3 years ago here https://gist.github.com/canpoyrazoglu/e85a47701a7be291dbd05372e8e5f76f it also touches a few other things but the relevant part is where it changes `RCTImageUtils.m` (for images) and `RCTConvert.m` (for color values). not sure if the same exact patch file would work with current version but you can apply the changes manually accordingly to UIColor and UIImage initializers.